# How to read a .cfg file in Haskell

Tags: file, haskell

I'm working on a function that reads two files; the first one is a ".cfg" file, who describes a grammar in CNF, and the second one is a ".txt" with a string. I have to use the grammar from the "cfg" file to verify the string from the second file using CYK algorithm. Each file of the .cfg defines a rule of the grammar, accepting empty lines that doesn't contains any rule, as well as the coments (using #).

My problem is that I'm a new learner and I don't know how to exactly read that .cfg file to assign each line to a rule. I think that maybe I can use a loop who reads each line until EOF or use hIsEOF as I read in a similar question, but being a cfg file I don't know if it should be treated in a different way or is the same as another file.

The description of the grammar follows the structure **symbol ::= symbol symbol** or **symbol ::= < terminal>** (without the space).

This is an example of the .cfg file I need to read:

```
S ::= <number>   # This is the initial term
S ::= <id>
S ::= L N

N ::= B R
L ::= <lparen>
R ::= <rparen>

B ::= S B
B ::= <number>
B ::= <id>
B ::= L N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to read a file, but all will need to use the IO Monad.

Try using [`withFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile) :: `FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r`

You can then use [`hGetLine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetLine) to read each line of the file, or if the file is short use [`hGetContents`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents) to get everything in the file and work on the resulting text in pure code.

At some point you will need a parser.  Writing one by hand is a pain, so read the documentation on the [Parsec library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried what you suggested and it worked, I just need to filtrate the ":=" caracter on every line and I'll test if my CYK algorithm works.